# How to capture my post request when I send a form to a server?

Tags: html, http, macos, tcp, packet-sniffers

I face some problem with a form on a web server. To solve it I want to know what exactly gets sent, when I click the submit button. How can I sniff the packets and see the parameters who get sent? Is there a good tool for mac to sniff exactly this post request I am doing?

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way is using a GET and see what's being sent via the browsers' query (altough the way you are sending could be AJAX and this method won't work).

Aditionally you can use Firefox's Firebug to see what's being sent.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I sniff the packets and see the parameters who get sent?

You can use tools as Wireshark (Windows, Linux, ...), NetworkMiner (Windows, Linux, ...) or Xplico (Linux). With each of these tools you can capture the network traffic to view the HTTP-request and the HTTP-response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow... you seem to be answering many old questions with accepted answers... you may find it much more productive to focus on recent questions with no correct or accepted answer.